# Why two process are staring with one java command

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I have spring boot jar file which I want to run with "op" user ( a user without password ) in the background.

```
sudo -u op nohup java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev order-processor.jar &
```

When I see the process using

```
ps aux | grep order-processor
```

it is has started 2 process  one with root another with op user

[image]

I want to know why it is happening also how to fix the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. There's nothing to fix. `sudo` is the command you ran to run java as another user. It has a `java` child process running as user `op`. When `java` exits so will `sudo`.

Comment: How should I run for one process? what research should I have done before asking this question here could you please lead me any article?

Comment: Why do you want only one process? Two processes is normal. What is the problem?

Comment: One is `sudo`, one is `java`. Try running `sudo sleep 60` and you'll see two processes: `sudo` and its `sleep` child process.